# If $|\omega|,|z|\le1$ then what are the possible values of them st. $|z+i\omega|=|z-i\bar \omega|=2$?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|\omega|,|z|\le1$ then what are the possible values of them st. $|z+i\omega|=|z-i\bar \omega|=2$?

When I tried, i resulted in two circles touching each other at z, but am not sure how to find possible values of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have that $|z+iw|=2$ and we have that the lengths are smaller equal then $1$. we get $iw=z$ similarly we get $-i\bar{w}=z$. If we now write $w=a+bi$ and $z=c+di$ this gives the following equations $-b+ai=c+di$ and $-b-ai=c+di$. This gives $c=-b$ and $a=d=-a\Rightarrow d=a=0$ thus we get that $|c|=|-b|=1$ thus the solution will be $z=1$ and $w=-i$ or $z=-1$ and $b=i$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that $z$ has to be distance $2$ away from both $-i\omega$ and $\overline{-i\omega}$, while these numbers are all within distance $1$ from the origin.

Comment: I guess I didn't read closely before posting. The original question is unchanged. Comments withdrawn.